# How to avoid manually reloading vs code extension every time i make changes?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, f5

I am developing a VS Code extension, and each time I run the extension, it opens a new instance of VS Code, showing the recent changes. However, this process becomes cumbersome, particularly when using VS Code remote, as it requires entering my password twice. Is there a way to avoid this repetitive behavior?

Unfortunately, there isn't a refresh button in vs code through which i can see recent changes without having to close the instance and press f5 to open a new one again in order to see recent changes.

Answer (score 0):

By "run the extension" I assume you mean you start a debug session. Is that correct? If so  then that's the normal way of developing a VS Code extension. The new code cannot be installed in the normal VS Code instance, but needs that development host to allow testing and debugging it.

So, it's not a manual reload you encounter, but the way how extension development works.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but is there a way to avoid starting a new instance every time to view the smallest changes?

Comment: No way, no. Like with any other application that's being developed: it must be restarted to load the changes. There's one exception though: hot module reloading in web development, but that's a different thing.